# view input to 2 decimal places

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a decimal property in my VM:

```
    [Required, Display(Name = "Manual Payment Amount")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal EnteredPaymentAmount { get; set; }
```

the View looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteredPaymentAmount, new { style = "width:200px", maxlength = Model.MaximumPaymentAmount.ToString("N").Length })
```

I want to limit the input to only have 2 decimal places

What is the best way of doing this? I tried to apply the DisplayFormat but also the format on the TextBoxFor but that still passed the validation meaning I can enter say 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some client side plugin that would allow you to define a regular expression for the allowed input. For example the [`jQuery maskedInput`](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: thanks. I ended up using the following:----- $('input#EnteredPaymentAmount').blur(function () {
                var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
                var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
                $(this).val(cleanNum);
            });

Comment: Yes, that's also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
@{var formated = String.Format("{0:0.00}", EnteredPaymentAmount);}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteredPaymentAmount, formated, new { id = "id"})
```

EDIT:-

You can try to use `EditorFor` also

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EnteredPaymentAmount)
```

Comment: Can you try with @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EnteredPaymentAmount) instead of TextFor ?

Comment: did that too and still no go.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#EnteredPaymentAmount').blur(function () {
                var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
                var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
                $(this).val(cleanNum);
            });
```

I used the above code and it worked just fine.